# Can I have a T-score more than 100?

Tags: data-transformation

I am calculating the T-scores of students but I have more than 100 in some of the T-scores. This is how am calculating it:

$$T = 50 + \frac{10({\rm score}-{\rm mean})}{{\rm sd}}$$

Comment: I do not have experience with students, but if the score distribution is normal, 5 standard deviations above the mean is more or less "one in a million" :)

Comment: Note that the "t-score" at issue here is *not* related to [student's $t$-distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student%27s_t-distribution). This is a way scores (eg, test scores) are standardized in education to make scores more comparable & interpretable.

Comment: @gung: so a "t-score" is z-score times 10 plus 50?

Comment: @amoeba, the T score (note, usually upper case) is a way of scaling scores used in psychometrics sometimes. Kind of like the way that IQ has mean = 100, and SD = 15. http://faculty.pepperdine.edu/shimels/Courses/Files/ConvTable.pdf

Comment: are 'mean' and 'sd' sample quantities, or in some sense population quantities?

Comment: If it's based on sample quantities, you need at least 26 observations to get a z-score more than 5 (and hence $50+10z>100$). [If it's based on some external population mean and sd it might instead simply indicate you have at least some observations from a different population to that.]

Answer (score 4):

There is no reason why some specific observations in your data cannot have an extreme value - so observations more than 5 SD above the mean (which is what you have found with your formula) are certainly possible.

However, we do know that by [Chebyshev's inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev's_inequality) - no more than about 4% of all of your observations should be more than 5 SD away from the mean regardless of how data is distributed.  If you are finding more than 4% of your observations with such high values - you probably have a math error somewhere in your process.

Comment: For example, if 99 students had a raw score of 0% and the 100th student had a raw score of 100%, then the mean score would be 1% with a standard deviation of 10%. The score of 100% would be transformed to 149 in this case.